# wicket how to update a column value in a table when clicking on an ajaxlink of another column

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a table, that has a column of links and another column of booleans, when I click on a link, the boolean of the other column should change to the opposite value, i.e., if its false to true and vice-versa.--> This is my goal.

This is a simplified description, the table has more columns that are not described here and I have a large number of classes.

In the main class, I add the table, and make the columns, as the excerpt below

Main.class

```
private void onInit(){
   table=new BootstrapFallbackDefaultDataTable<PaymentArea,String>("payment-table", makeColumns(), paymentDetailsDataProvide, 10);
   table.setOutputMarkupId(true);
   add(table)
}

private List<IColumn<PaymentArea,String>> makeColumns(){

  List<IColumn<PaymentArea,String>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
  //some columns are added as PropertyColumn
  //the next column is the one that have the ajaxLink
  columns.add(new AbstractColumn<PaymentArea,String>(new StringResourceModel("payment-actions",this,null)){
      @Override
      public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<PaymentArea>> item, String componentId, IModel<PaymentArea> rowmodel)
     {
         currentGoal = service.getPollById(rowmodel.getObject().getPaymentGUID()).getVoted();
         invoiceId = rowmodel.getObject().getInvoiceGUID();
         paymentId = rowmodel.getObject().getPaymentGUID();
         item.add(new ContestButtonPayment2(componentId, currentGoal, invoiceId, paymentId));
         });
      //next column is the column that should be updated 
   columns.add(new AbstractColumn<PaymentArea, String>(new StringResourceModel("payment-contest",this,null)
   {
     @Override
     public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<PaymentArea>> item, String componentId, IModel<PaymentArea> rowmodel)
     {
        currentGoal = service.getPollById(rowmodel.getObject().getPaymentGUID()).getVoted();
        item.add(new ConstestedColumn2(componentId, currentGoal));         
      }
  });
  return columns;
}
}
```

The next class is the class that defines the AjaxLink, for the column and for each row of the table.

ContestButtonPayment2.java

```
 import java.util.List;
 import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
 import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink;
 import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
 import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
 import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;
 import nl.riskco.liberobc.client.business.services.IPollService;
 import nl.riskco.liberobc.client.business.services.impl.PollServiceImpl;
 import nl.riskco.liberobc.web.pages.details.invoices.main.LegendForButtons;

 public class ContestButtonPayment2 extends Panel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private IPollService service;
private LegendForButtons text;
private Label label;


public ContestButtonPayment2(String componentId, List<String> currentGoal, String invoiceId, String paymentId){

    super(componentId);
    service = new PollServiceImpl();

    initiateButton(currentGoal);

    add(new AjaxLink("voteLink"){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {                 
            if(!currentGoal.contains("X"))
            {
                service.votePayment(paymentId,invoiceId);
                text.setLegend("Revoke");
            }//close if

            else if(currentGoal.contains("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("payment: " + paymentId + " invoiceId: " + invoiceId);
                service.revokePaymentVote(paymentId);
                text.setLegend("Contest");      
            }

        else{ 
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }   

        //Update link
        target.add(this);
    }//close onclick
}.add(label));//close ajaxLink
 }
public void initiateButton(List<String> currentGoal){

    text = new LegendForButtons();

    if(!currentGoal.contains("X"))
        {
            text.setLegend("Contest");
        }
    else
            text.setLegend("Revoke");

    label = new Label("buttonLabel", new PropertyModel(text,"legend"));
}
 }
```

The class that needs to be updated

ConstestedColumn2.java

```
 import java.util.List;
 import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
 import nl.riskco.Y.web.pages.utils.VoteBooleanLabelPanel;

 public class ContestedColumn2 extends Panel{

private boolean resultX, resultY, resultZ;
private VoteBooleanLabelPanel labelX;
private VoteBooleanLabelPanel labelY;
private VoteBooleanLabelPanel labelZ;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ContestedColumn2(String id, List<String> currentGoal){       
    super(id);

    resultX = currentGoal.contains("X");
    labelX = new VoteBooleanLabelPanel("labelX", "X", resultX);
    labelX.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(labelX);

    resultY = currentGoal.contains("Y");
    labelY = new VoteBooleanLabelPanel("labelY", "Y", resultY);
    labelY.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(labelY);

    resultZ= currentGoal.contains("Z");
    labelZ = new VoteBooleanLabelPanel("labelZ", "Z", resultZ);
    labelZ.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(labelZ);

}
public ContestedColumn2(String id){
    super(id);


}
  }
```

VoteBooleanLabelPanel.java

```
 import org.apache.wicket.AttributeModifier;
 import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
 import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
 import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;

 public class VoteBooleanLabelPanel extends Panel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Label label;
private boolean value;
public VoteBooleanLabelPanel(final String id, String text, boolean value) {

    super(id);
    String voteLabel = getCssClass(value);

    label = new Label("icon", text);
    label.add(new AttributeModifier("class",voteLabel));
    add(label);
}

public VoteBooleanLabelPanel(final String id, String text){
    super(id);

    String voteLabel = getCssClass(value);

    this.value = false;

    label = new Label("icon", text);
    label.add(new AttributeModifier("class",voteLabel));
    add(label);
}

public void updateLabel(boolean value, AjaxRequestTarget target){
    String voteLabel = getCssClass(value);
    label.add(new AttributeModifier("class",voteLabel));
    label.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    target.add(label);
}

private String getCssClass(boolean value){
    if(value)
        return "label label-danger";
    else
        return "label label-default";
}
```

}

To understand better what is this last java class, below is its html

```
 <wicket:panel>
    <h4><span wicket:id="labelX"></span> <span wicket:id="labelY"></span> <span wicket:id="labelZ"></span></h4>
 </wicket:panel>
```

Summary:
I would like when clicking on the link of row1 column2 to update the labelX values in the row1 column3 of the table.

labelX is represented on the table column (next to labelY and labelZ) as a X inside a grey square if its value is false and red if its value is true.

Does anyone knows how to this?
I think that I should use events, but I don't know how to it since I have so many classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most clean way is to use Wicket events.
In `onClick()` broadcast an event with a payload, e.g.:

```
send(findParent(DataTable.class), Broadcast.BREADTH, new YourPayload(guid, target));
```

`guid` is `getPaymentGUID()` and `target` is the AjaxRequestTarget.
The event will be sent to the parent data table and from there it will be broadcasted to all its children.

In ConstestedColumn2.java you need to override `onEvent(IEvent)` and if the `guid` is the same then use the payload to update itself.

```
@Override public void onEvent(IEvent event) {
    Object payload = event.getPayload();
    if (payload instanceOf YourPayload) {
      YourPayload yourPayload  = (YourPayload) payload;
      if (myGuid.equals(yourPayload.getGuid()) {
        // some business logic
        yourPayload.getTarget().add(this);
        event.stop(); // no need to visit more children
      }
    }
}
```